# For a class that will do some processing on given data, is it better to do the work on instantiation or via a public method?

Tags: oop, architecture

I have a question about best practice in OOP.

Say I have a class that is in charge of receiving some inputs and do some processing in order to make an output result available.

Is it recommended to provide all the inputs and to do the processing on instantiation, for example like this :

```
public class Processor
{
    private ProcessorConfig config;
    private ProcessorInputData inputData;

    public ProcessorResults Results { get; set; }

    public Processor(ProcessorConfig config, ProcessorInputData inputData)
    {
        this.config = config;
        this.inputData = inputData;

        Process();
    }

    private void Process()
    {
        // private function that does the processing using the the inputData
        // and constructs the public Results object
    }
    ...
} // class Processor

public class ProcessorExample
{
  public static Example()
  {
     ProcessorConfig config = GetConfigFromSomeWhere();
     ProcessorInputData inputData = GetInputDataFromSomeWhere();
     Processor processor = new Processor(config, inputData);
     ProcessorResults results = processor.Results;
  }
} // class ProcessorExample
```

Or would it be better to provide some initial inputs on instantiation (configuration parameters) and have a separate function to call when it is required to do the processing on some data, like this :

```
public class Processor
{
    private ProcessorConfig config;

    public Processor(ProcessorConfig config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public ProcessorResults Process(ProcessorInputData inputData)
    {
        // public function to call with inputData,
        // doing the processing and returning a Results object
    }
    ...
} // class Processor

public class ProcessorExample
{
  public static Example()
  {
     ProcessorConfig config = GetConfigFromSomeWhere();
     Processor processor = new Processor(config);

     ProcessorInputData inputData = GetInputDataFromSomeWhere();
     ProcessorResults results = processor.Process(inputData);
  }
} // class ProcessorExample
```

Any idea which is best ?

Answer (score 0):

Something about "Best Practices" is that are very subjective. There is no "only bad" or "only good", but, "this one is a best practice under these circumstances".

I personally, prefer the second version. Because: where the method is executed, after the parameters are assigned.

This give you more control of the actions.

Are the operations going to be executed several times ?

If the answer is yes, is common to use the second option.

If the answer, is No, just once, usually the first option is commonly used.